# copy_user_enhanced_fast_string consuming lot of CPU in UDP reader thread

Tags: linux, udp

I have a UDP application that reads multi-datagrams from from UDP socket in IO reader thread. Post reading multidatagram from socket, multidatagram to passed to another to thread via queue for further processing. While analying my IO reader thread via perf tool, I saw that copy_user_enhanced_fast_string() is using maximum CPU.

1. Why I am seeing copy_user_enhanced_fast_string() at top most consumer of IO reader thread?
2. What I can do so that my thread doesn't spend so much time in copy_user_enhanced_fast_string()